# Python iterate slice object

Tags: python, iteration, slice

If I have a slice object

```
s = slice(a,b,c)
```

and an array length `n`, is there a nice readymade iterator for the elements so that I can do something like:

```
for index in FUNCTION_I_WANT(s, n):
    do_whatever(index)
```

and have it behave like slicing of lists, beyond the really horrible:

```
def HACKY_VERSION_OF_FUNCTION_I_WANT(s,n):
    yield range(n).__getitem__(s)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. What is the function supposed to do? What does the array (list?) have to do with the slice object?

Comment: @Blender what array (list)? The `n`? That's just a number where it should stop, probably best interpreted as the length of a list, though not necessarily.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
def FUNCTION_I_WANT(s, n):
  return range(*s.indices(n))
```

Comment: aha, that's how it is supposed to work. That is not obvious ;)